# Call a toggle function from sub child reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
class Template extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        isMenuVisible: false,
        isVideoModelVisible: false,
        loading: 'is-loading'
    }
    this.handleToggleVideoModel = this.handleToggleVideoModel.bind(this)

}

 handleToggleVideoModel() {
    alert('test handleToggleVideoModel ');
    console.log('layout');
    this.setState({
        isVideoModelVisible: !this.state.isVideoModelVisible
    })
}
render() {
    const { children } = this.props
    return (

       {children()}

    )
}
}
Template.propTypes = {
children: React.PropTypes.func,
handleToggleVideoModel: React.PropTypes.func
}

export default Template
```

pages/index.js which is rendered in Above Template file in {children()}

```
class HomeIndex extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleToggleVideoModel = this.handleToggleVideoModel.bind(this)
}
render() {
return (
        <div>
            <Helmet>
                <title>{siteTitle}</title>
                <meta name="description" content={siteDescription} />
            </Helmet>

            <Banner onToggleVideoModel= 
{this.props.handleToggleVideoModel}/>
        )
    }

}
HomeIndex.propTypes = {

onToggleVideoModel: React.PropTypes.func
}

export default HomeIndex
```

components/Banner.js

```
const Banner = (props) => (
<section id="banner" className="major">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" className="button next" onClick= 
{props.onToggleVideoModel}>Watch video</a></li>
</section>
)
export default Banner
```

**How can i don that?**
handleToggleVideoModel i want to call from Banner.js which is Grand child of layout/index Parent layuts/index.js.
child pages/index.js 
grandchild components/Banner.js
I am stuck in this any body has idea that how can i access handleToggleVideoModel from Banner suggest me solutions.

Comment: simply pass this function as a props to child component

Answer (score 0):

Pass method reference from Component 1 to component 2 like this:

```
<Component 2  toggle={this.handleToggleVideoModel}/>
```

Now again pass this reference to Component 4 like this from Component 2

```
<Component 4 toggle={this.props.handleToggleVideoModel} />
```

Now you can call this function from Component 4 like this:

```
this.props.handleToggleVideoModel
```

Comment: I am using https://www.gatsbyjs.org/ GetsBy
in which there is layout/index,js which contain this function 
and they  const { children } = this.props take childern and render {children()}
this render contain HomeIndex.js file which my Component 2
and inside Component 2 i have 
 <Banner onToggleVideoModel={this.props.handleToggleVideoModel}/>
and in Banner i have done
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" className="button next" onClick={props.handleToggleVideoModel}>Watch video</a></li>

Now this takes me to Component 2 instead of layout which is parent

Comment: In short how can i pass in {Childern} to Compnent2
they are not doing like <Component 2  toggle={this.handleToggleVideoModel}/>
just calling {childern} and childern render\ Compnent2